# Add target="_blank" to all links BUT internal site links

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I have the following code that will add `target="_blank"` to all links:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href^='http://']").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

How would I re-write the above code to target all links except links that are internal.

IE:

`http://www.my-site.com/` = internal link

`http://www.other-site.com/` = external link

Also how would I target any links that do not begin with `http://` but are not internal?

I am looking for a jQuery solution.

Comment: What kind of external links would you want to target that don't begin with `http://`? Just `https://`?

Comment: @Marcel - I have a few links that start wth `ftp` but in reality those links I can manually add. Other than that yes `https://`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just chain your selectors:

```
$("a[href^='http']:not([href^='http://www.mysite.com'])").attr("target","_blank");
```

This will select all links starting with `http` (so not relative internals) but not starting with `http://www.mysite.com` (so not the absolute internals either).

Comment: Not really, for modern capable browsers that support these CSS3 selectors the selection is handled natively by the browser, and for older browsers the Sizzle selector engine is more than capable of performing this one-time search in milliseconds on a modern computer. At any rate it won't be (much) slower than @Marcel's solution which loops over more elements and applies a string search to all of them.

Comment: Will this also add `target="_blank"` to `https` or should I use `$("a[href^='https']:not...`?

Answer (score 4):

I use the following bit of JavaScript when using jQuery. It also adds a class to external links and includes tracking of outgoing links in Google Analytics. Just remove it if you don't use Google Analytics.

You can use a more specific selector if you don't want this to hit all links on a page, for example `$("#main a[href^=http]")`.

```
$("a[href^=http]")
  .each(function(){
    // this part checks if the link is external
    if (this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1){
      // add a class for external links
      $(this).addClass("ext")
        // make the link open in a new tab/window
        .attr({ "target":"_blank", "rel":"external" })
        // track clicks of external links if you use Google Analytics
        .click(function(){
          _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Outgoing link", "click", $(this).attr("href")]);
        });
    }
  });
```

Comment: My only recommendation is to use .toLowerCase() when performing the comparison.